# Rails 7: How to pass a variable from one controller to the next

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, it used to be possible to pass a variable (here: `:anchor`) from one controller to the next, by calling something like:

```
redirect_to user_profile_path(anchor: 'details')
```

But trying to catch `:anchor` in the next controller, i.e. like so...

```
puts params[:anchor].inspect
puts request.params[:anchor].inspect
```

...fails. Why?

(I'm on Rails 7, in case it matters.)

***EDIT:***

Strangely enough, when I use a different `key`, i.e. `test`...

```
redirect_to user_profile_path(anchor: 'details', test: 'test-value')
```

...then...

```
puts params[:test].inspect
```

...correctly returns the value, in the log file:

```
'test-value'
```

Comment: please add the log of the request

Comment: @dbugger - Both of the `puts` return simply `nil` in the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really has very little to do with Rails and more with how browsers and URI's work.

Anchor is a special option for [url_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) for that adds a [URI Fragment (aka anchor or hash)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) to the URL.

Clients do not send the URI fragment to the server when requesting a URI. Its transparent to the server by design. But the client will accept the fragment from the server.

If you want to pass additional information from the client to the server in a GET request you need to do it either by adding a query string parameter, custom headers or a cookie.

Using `user_profile_path(anchor: 'details', test: 'test-value')` works since `test:` is not a named option and will instead add a query string parameter.